# Last hook to be called after entity save?

Tags: 7, hooks, entities

Of the various hooks called during the entity save process, which is the very last to be called?

Is there a way to trigger an event after the entity has been created, after all fields have been saved, after caches updated, etc? So that, when a user saves the update form, this action is the very last thing to happen before the redirect page is loaded?

If it's not strictly part of the save process, that's fine. What matters is: it's called after everything to do with an entity being saved. If there's a way of hooking some form function and reliably identifying from the data in there that a save process has been completed, or defining some callback, that's fine by me.

(context: I've got a problem where field caches are being created that caused newly created nodes, and other fieldable entity types, to load as if they are blank and as if they have no field data - but all attempts so far using cache_get and cache_clear_all don't find the cache - it's being created late in the process. So I'm looking for the latest possible hook which will definitely get it)

(Relevant info: [`hook_entity_postsave` doesn't exist](http://drupal.org/node/1362378), and is one of those core issues that got stuck months and months ago)

Comment: I've written a module that provides what you're looking for. You can find the details here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308465/post-save-callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The various wrapper functions ([`node_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/7), [`user_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_save/7), etc.) are responsible for resetting the entity cache after the save method has been invoked on an entity controller.

If you take the `user_save()` function as an example, this cache reset happens *after* the function invokes the various entity hooks (same goes for `node_load()`)

That in mind, I think the question then becomes "What is the last hook to be called *during* an entity save"?...and the answer is `hook_entity_update()` / `hook_entity_insert()`. But, they are called before the cache is reset (for obvious reasons).

The `entity_save()` method just invokes the save handler for that particular entity type, and doesn't invoke any hooks of its own, so really your only options are:

- Roll your own entity controller for the various entities you need to intercept, changing the `save()` method to invoke a hook after the cache has been cleared.
- Hack/patch the existing entity controllers with the same code.

Neither are particularly attractive options but unless there's a solution available at a higher level that I'm not seeing, I don't think you've got much choice.

Comment: Argh! What about during the redirection process? node_save() etc must call a function to trigger the page redirection after completing everything and saving caches - is there any way of using this? Or, assuming as with nodes that it redirects to the newly saved entity, any way of triggering a cache clear the first time an entity is viewed?

Comment: It's the form handler that performs the redirect, not the `_save()` function, so I guess you could hook into the form and add a submit handler _to the end of the array of submit functions_ (so it gets run last). In your submit handler the `_save()` function will have been run, and presumably the caches cleared, so you can intercept it at the right time. But again I don't think there's a generic solution that will work across all entity types, and it will only work if the entity is created via a form, and not programatically.

Comment: Forcing a cache clear when the entity is first viewed would require keeping a variable somewhere (perhaps a custom table) for each entity that determines whether or not that cache flush has been run, and performs it if not. So you'll need to store entity_type, bundle, and entity_id along with that boolean value (similar to the field_data_* tables). `hook_entity_view()` would be the place for that logic.

Comment: The option in your first comment sounds like it could be the way to go. One more question though if you don't mind: it does sound like my problem cache is the one created at the end of the entity_save process, which makes me wonder how it can be that the field cache created doesn't match the entity object that has just been saved. But I can't find the code that calls the cache creation in entity_save or node_save to begin debugging - only code that clears the old cache. Would it be in the entity class definition? Not sure where to look for that. Thanks

Comment: The caching decisions happen at a slightly lower level than `node_save()`...in the [`DrupalDefaultEntityController`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/DrupalDefaultEntityController/7) class (which `NodeController` extends). In a nutshell it's the [`DrupalDefaultEntityController::load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/function/DrupalDefaultEntityController%3A%3Aload/7) function which queries the cache, and forces a live load of the data if a suitable cache cannot be found. That might be the best place to start back-tracking from

Comment: Thanks, that was a massive help! If anyone with a similar problem finds this via google, I'm 99% sure that my cache problem stems from some code that calls `entity_load()` with the 4th parameter set to true. Which leads me to a new question... http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39338/how-to-refresh-entity-from-entity-load-reloading-the-entity-as-it-is-now

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to execute a view after a node was saved. The node appeared in the view but had old data on the fields despite just having been saved.  Subsequent calls to the view had the latest field values.

I called the following at the start of my hook_node_update which appears to solve the problem (for me).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_update().
 */
function mymodule_node_update($node) {
  // Clear internal properties.                                           
  unset($node->is_new);                                                   
  unset($node->original);                                                 
  // Clear the static loading cache.                                      
  entity_get_controller('node')->resetCache(array($node->nid));  

  // Rest of my code e.g. execute a view.
}
```

This reset cache command is what is run by the node_save function after invoking all the hook_node_update's.

Comment: Interesting. Would that have essentially the same effect as what is suggested in the answer to [this question about loading an entity bypassing the existing cache data](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39338/how-to-refresh-entity-from-entity-load-reloading-the-entity-as-it-is-now?lq=1), or is there are difference you know of in the process?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an addon module which provides hook to invoke after an entity is saved. It's called [Hook Post Action](https://drupal.org/project/hook_post_action). This was already answered [on stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308465/post-save-callback).