# How Reliable is node_save?

Tags: nodes

When using node_save, how sure can one be that it did what it was supposed to do?

At the moment after any call to node_save I have been checking that the required property did succesfully update. For example:

```
$node->field_some_field['und'][0] = array('tid' => $some_taxonomy);
node_save($node);

if($node->field_some_field['und'][0]['tid'] == $some_taxonomy) {
    return TRUE;
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

Is this necessary? Or is there a better way to perform the check?

Edit: As an example, say I want to update a node's taxonomy programatically - it would be useful to know if it worked or not. I think it's just bad in general for things to fail silently.

Comment: +1 to Jimajammas answers, but I think you could provide some more context to this. Why would it be necessary to do the check? I've never seen even a remotely similar requirement on any of my sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to believe that `node_save()` is doing its job.  But, if you don't, `node_save($node)` is declared as sending $node by reference, so, if anything changes `$node` during the `node_presave()` hook, it will be reflected in `$node` after the fact.  That notwithstanding, if you wanted to be perfectly sure, you could do something like:

```
$nid=$node->nid;
node_load(NULL, NULL, TRUE);
$node=node_load($nid);

if ($node->.....
```

which would clear any node caches in your page and then reload the node from the database before your `if` check.

ADDITION:

From your example, the failure logic imho should be in your generation of the taxonomy value, not in worrying about if `node_save()` has or hasn't done its job.  For example:

```
   // assuming we have $node populated

   $some_taxonomy=programmatically_created_tid($args);

   if ($some_taxonomy !== FALSE) { 
     $node->field_some_field['und'][0] = array('tid' => $some_taxonomy);
   } else {
     drupal_set_message(....
     watchdog(.....
   }
```

where your function looks something like this:

```
   function programmatically_created_tid($args) {

     // do whatever logic is necessary to generate the tid

     if ($success) { // success 
       return $tid;
     } else {
       return FALSE;
     }
   }
```

would alert the user to the problem you are actually concerned about.

Comment: Would this not only work if node_save() is creating the object, not updating it? If node_save() has failed to update a pre-existing node, it will still load. Is there not a timestamp ("last_updated" or something) in the node object? If so, wouldn't it be possible to check this timestamp before and after node_save() and see if it has changed? Also, see the answer to [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39338/how-to-refresh-entity-from-entity-load-reloading-the-entity-as-it-is-now) - you don't need to clear the whole node cache to reload one node from the database.

Comment: Like @letharion, I've never seen a real world case where node_save() hasn't done its job.  But to your first question, this should work for both new and updated nodes as the load may work but if there is a problem, the fields won't be populated correctly in either case. However, if there is such a case, I don't know why you would rely upon $node->changed (the timestamp) to be your validity test instead of checking the value of the field you are most concerned about.  As for entity_load_unchanged(), sure enough, that does look like a nifty way of doing things without clearing the page's cache.